# Method for solving this differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm currently studying general birth-death processes and would please like some more details on something in the notes I'm reading.

It gives what it calls 'the backwards Kolmogorov equation for the generating function' as

$\partial_{t}F(s,t)=\alpha F^{2} -(\alpha+\beta)F+\beta$

With boundary equation $F(s,0)=s$

Then gives the solution as

$F=\cfrac{(s\alpha - \beta)e^{-\lambda t}+\beta(1-s)}{(s\alpha - \beta)e^{-\lambda t}+\alpha(1-s)}$

Where $\lambda = \alpha - \beta$

It says that this was solved by separation of variables, I understand that this means letting $F=S(s)T(t)$, but I don't know enough about differential equations to get from the PDE to the solution for F. I would really appreciate if someone could provide a worked solution so that I can see the steps involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically an ODE:
$$\frac{dF}{dt}=aF^2-(a+b)F+b \implies \int \frac{dF}{aF^2-(a+b)F+b}=\int dt+C$$
$$\implies \int \frac{dF}{(aF-b))(F-1)}=t+C \implies \frac{1}{b-a} \int \left(\frac{a}{aF-b}-\frac{1}{F-1}\right) dF=t+C$$
$$\implies \ln(aF-b)-\ln(F-1)=(b-a)t+C_1 \implies \frac{aF-b}{F-1}=De^{ct}, c=b-a.$$
$$\implies F=\frac{b-De^{ct}}{a-De^{ct}},~~ D=\frac{as-b}{s-1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!